# GCP function refuses to deploy - error fetching storage source: generic::unknown: retry budget exhausted (3 attempts)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a Google Cloud HTTP function, using this line in zsh shell (Arch Linux):

```
gcloud functions deploy testing --runtime python38 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

when the function is only [main.py]:

```
def testing(request):
   print("yes")
   return 'finished', 200
```

and this is the error it is giving:

[image]

ERROR:

> error fetching storage source: generic::unknown: retry budget exhausted (3 attempts): fetching gcs source: unpacking source from gcs: source fetch container exited with non-zero status: 1

However, the funny thing is, that the other google cloud functions that I have (some are HTTP-trigger and some are Cloud Storage-trigger) deploy fine. The only thing I think may be the issue is a cloud function amount limit (?? maybe??)

Help me please

Comment: I have similar issue since yesterday. My issue happens with a newly created Firebase project, and not able to deploy functions yet.

Comment: I honestly need a solution asap. This issue is frustrating

Comment: The same here! I'll share if I can figure out a solution, it is frustrating indeed

Comment: In my case, the problem was caused by conflicting `nodejs` versions!  
I've solved my case by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/65955925/492918

Comment: :( but i need a solution for my problem as welll

Comment: Just to make sure, are you still having the issue? I tried to replicate on my side and everything worked smoothly

Comment: Yes i am still experiencing it

Comment: These look like isolated issues and this looks like an issue behind the scenes, the best way to get more information is by reaching to GCP support via [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

as a workaround try to deploy your code GCP console (web UI)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because you haven't specified the directory of the code. To do this, flag `--source` should be used as well. Full example command `gcloud functions deploy function_name --gen2 --runtime=python311 --region=europe-central2 --source=dlp-trigger --entry-point=start_dataflow_process --trigger-topic=run_topic`

Remember to create a directory named `dlp-trigger` and put there module `main.py` that contains the code along with the `requirements.txt`